# error while installing google maps package

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

i tried to install google maps package but it doesn't work when i run the app
here is the **pubspec.yaml**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzRbA.png)

**and the error is :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1CT.png)

i already tried aloder versions like google-maps:1-0-0 but it doesn't work and also updating the sdk will effect all the project

Comment: Did you use 'flutter pub get' after adding that line in pubspec.yaml? You need to.

Comment: What flutter version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The minimum sdk must be greater that 20 for the plugin to use.

Go to `android -> app -> build.grade` and update the values as following

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 31
```

stop the emulator and run the app again